# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException while updating database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is the error i'm getting:

```
07-20 11:04:45.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1905): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dosemanager1.ui/com.dosemanager.ui.ActivityDisplayMedicineDetails}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

I want to update the details of a particular medicine. So, i use this code:

```
public int updateMedicine(MedicineDetails medicine, String oldTitle){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DOSE_NAME, medicine.getDoseName());
    values.put(KEY_DOSE_SCHEDULE, medicine.getDoseSchedule().getTimeInMillis());
    values.put(KEY_DOSE_REPEAT, medicine.getDoseRepeat());
    values.put(KEY_DOSE_FREQUENCY, medicine.getDoseFrequency());
    values.put(KEY_DOSE_OTHER_NOTES, medicine.getOtherNotes());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_MEDICINES, values, KEY_DOSE_NAME + " = ?",
            new String[] { oldTitle });
}
```

Now, it tells me that the details are updated in a toast i've made elsewhere, but when i try displaying the updated details, i get the `CursorIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

This is my code for returning a single `MedicineDetails` object:

```
public MedicineDetails getSingleMedicine(String title) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEDICINES, new String[] { KEY_ID_DOSE, KEY_DOSE_NAME, KEY_DOSE_SCHEDULE, 
            KEY_DOSE_REPEAT, KEY_DOSE_FREQUENCY, KEY_DOSE_OTHER_NOTES},
            KEY_DOSE_NAME + "=?",
            new String[] { title }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    cal.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(2));
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());

    MedicineDetails singleDetail = new MedicineDetails(cursor.getString(1), cal,
            cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));

    return singleDetail;
}
```

This is where i've created the table:

```
String CREATE_MEDICINES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEDICINES + "("
            + KEY_ID_DOSE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DOSE_NAME + " TEXT,"              
            + KEY_DOSE_SCHEDULE + " INTEGER, " + KEY_DOSE_REPEAT + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_DOSE_FREQUENCY + " TEXT," + KEY_DOSE_OTHER_NOTES + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MEDICINES_TABLE);
```

The same code works perfectly to display details of any medicine that i've NOT edited. So, i think there's something wrong with the update.

I've read a few similar problems, but none of the answers elsewhere could solve my issue.
What mistake am i making?

Comment: first of all check database table and data after update. then after try to get data and check cursor is not returning null value. i think its returning null values.

Answer (score 3):

The cursor returned by a query maybe empty but never null. If it is empty then `moveToFirst()` would return false, thus your code should be

```
MedicineDetails singleDetail;
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    cal.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(2));
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());

    MedicineDetails singleDetail = new MedicineDetails(cursor.getString(1), cal,
        cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
}

return singleDetail;
```

Comment: I tried that... now i'm getting a normal null pointer exception:

`07-20 11:43:13.334: E/AndroidRuntime(2375): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dosemanager1.ui/com.dosemanager.ui.ActivityDisplayMedicineDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: This is my modified code:

`if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{ ... ...  ... }
else Log.v("returning", "null");
return null;
`

The problem is that the log also didn't get printed!

Comment: Which line do you get NPE? You should check if the return value singleDetail is null or not.

Comment: No, I understand that i put a return null...so it HAS to give an exception. But then why didn't the log get printed?

Comment: Put a log inside the if to see if it is printed.

Comment: Yes, it prints inside...but not all. Strangely.

`Log.v("NAME", cursor.getString(1));

   Log.v("LASTCHECK", cursor.getString(3));  
   Log.v("PHONE", cursor.getString(4));
   System.out.println(cursor.getString(4));
`

everything is printing except `Log.v("PHONE", cursor.getString(4));`
... but the same `cursor.getString(4)` is printing with the SOP.

Comment: Log.d("NameOfClass", "Name = " + cursor.getString(1) + " Last Check = " + cursor.getString(3) + .....);